# Speed up nested for-loops in python / going through numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

Say I have 4 numpy arrays A,B,C,D , each the size of (256,256,1792).
I want to go through each element of those arrays and do something to it, *but* I need to do it in chunks of 256x256x256-cubes.

My code looks like this:

```
for l in range(7): 
    x, y, z, t = 0,0,0,0
    for m in range(a.shape[0]):
        for n in range(a.shape[1]):
            for o in range(256*l,256*(l+1)):
                t += D[m,n,o] * constant
                x += A[m,n,o] * D[m,n,o] * constant
                y += B[m,n,o] * D[m,n,o] * constant
                z += C[m,n,o] * D[m,n,o] * constant
    final = (x+y+z)/t
    doOutput(final)
```

The code works and outputs exactly what I want, but its awfully slow. I've read online that those kind of nested for loops should be avoided in python. What is the cleanest solution to it? (right now I'm trying to do this part of my code in C and somehow import it via Cython or other tools,  but I'd love a pure python solution)

Thanks

**Add on**

*Willem Van Onsem*'s Solution to the first part seems to work just fine and I think I comprehend it. But now I want to modify my values before summing them. It looks like

(within the outer l loop)

```
for m in range(a.shape[0]):
    for n in range(a.shape[1]):
        for o in range(256*l,256*(l+1)):
            R += (D[m,n,o] * constant * (A[m,n,o]**2 
            + B[m,n,o]**2 + C[m,n,o]**2)/t - final**2)
doOutput(R)
```

I obviously can't just square the sum `x = (A[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()**2*constant` since (A²+B²) != (A+B)²
How can I redo this last for loops?

Comment: What will you do with `x,y,z,t`? Here you only reset them, so only the last loop (`l = 6`) will actually matter...

Comment: it's just a small portion of my code. I work with those summed up values later on

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but since you are just adding term-by-term, you shouldn't need to split into square sections.  I seems like `t=np.sum(D)` and `x=np.sum(A*D)` unless you want to actually do something like `np.dot(A[:256],D[:256])`

Comment: @DanielForsman: the question states the OP wants to process *chunks* of 256x256x256.

Comment: @t.rathjen: what do you mean with "modifying my values". You do not modfy any of them, you only sum them up.

Comment: @t.rathjen: you can use `A**2` to obtain the *element-wise* square matrix.

Comment: I take the square of each element in A,B,C, add them up, multiply it with D, subtract the value of final and sum over all 256³ resulting values

Comment: @t.rathjen: mind that the result is a 256x256x256 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you update `t` with every element of `m in range(a.shape[0])`, `n in range(a.shape[1])` and `o in range(256*l,256*(l+1))`, you can substitute:

```
for m in range(a.shape[0]):
    for n in range(a.shape[1]):
        for o in range(256*l,256*(l+1)):
            t += D[m,n,o]
```

With:

```
t += D[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],256*l:256*(l+1)].sum()
```

The same for the other assignments. So you can rewrite your code to:

```
for l in range(7): 
    Dsub = D[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],256*l:256*(l+1)]
    x = (A[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()*constant
    y = (B[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()*constant
    z = (C[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1],256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()*constant
    t = Dsub.sum()*constant
   final = (x+y+z)/t
   doOutput(final)
```

Note that the `*` in *numpy* is the *element-wise* multiplication, **not** the matrix product. You can do the multiplication before the sum, but since the sum of a multiplications with a constant is equal to the multiplication of that constant with the sum, I think it is more efficient to do this out of the loop.

If `a.shape[0]` is equal to `D.shape[0]`, etc. You can use `:` instead of `:a.shape[0]`. Based on your question, **that seems to be the case**. so:

```
# only when `a.shape[0] == D.shape[0], a.shape[1] == D.shape[1] (and so for A, B and C)`
for l in range(7): 
    Dsub = D[:,:,256*l:256*(l+1)]
    x = (A[:,:,256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()*constant
    y = (B[:,:,256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()*constant
    z = (C[:,:,256*l:256*(l+1)]*Dsub).sum()*constant
    t = Dsub.sum()*constant
    final = (x+y+z)/t
    doOutput(final)
```

Processing the `.sum()` on the `numpy` level will boost performance since you do not convert values back and forth and with `.sum()`, you use a *tight* loop.

**EDIT**:

Your updated question does not change much. You can simply use:

```
m,n,_* = a.shape
lo,hi = 256*l,256*(l+1)
R = (D[:m,:n,lo:hi]*constant*(A[:m,:n,lo:hi]**2+B[:m,:n,lo:hi]**2+D[:m,:n,lo:hi]**2)/t-final**2)).sum()
doOutput(R)
```

Comment: okay, let me have a look at it. I don't quite get what you want to say with "Note that the * in numpy is the element-wise multiplication, not the matrix product." I do want to multiply those values element wise, but maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: @t.rathjen: it's just a note. Intuitively in Matlab/Octave for instance `*` is the matrix product. It is only a "justification" that it correct to use this for element-wise multiplication.

Comment: Your solution works fine for the first part of my question, but I added a second part to it.

Comment: I think you made a typo: "R += .." -> "R = ..."

But it works and the speed up is insane!

Comment: @t.rathjen: yeah indeed. But that does not really change much on what the question deals about.

Comment: I think one can leave out the `*constant` term altogether, as it is applied to the nominator and the denominator as well, and thus is cancelled out.